# What's the difference between finite and finitely generated algebras

Tags: abstract-algebra, definition

I didn't understand the difference between the two definitions:

[image]

I thought the definition of $B[a_1,\ldots,a_n]$ is exactly the one in the item (b), i.e., $B[a_1,\ldots,a_n]=Ba_1+\ldots+Ba_n$.

I need help

Thanks

Comment: For finitely generated, you can multiply the $a_i$ together.  Think of the difference between the polynomial ring $k[x]$ and a one-dimensional vector space $k\cdot v$

Answer (score 11):

An example: the polynomial $k[X]$ is a finitely generated $k$-algebra bit not a finite $k$-algebra.

An alternative, and possibly more illuminating, form of those definitions is the following: a ring $B$ contain a subring $A$ is

- *finitely generated* over $A$ if there is a finite subset $S\subseteq B$ such that the smallest **subring** of $B$ containing $A$ and $S$ is $B$ itself, and
- *finite* over $A$ if there is a finite subset $S\subseteq B$ such that the smallest **$A$-submodule** of $B$ containing $A$ and $S$ is $B$ itself.

Comment: Nice simple example!

Answer (score 3):

$B[a_1, a_2, ... , a_n]$ means the ring of polynomials of $a_1, a_2, ... , a_n$ with coefficients in $B$ i.e. 
$$B[a_1, a_2, ... , a_n] = \{f(a_1, a_2, ..., a_n) : f \in B[x_1, x_2, ..., x_n]\}$$
where $x_1, ..., x_n$ are distinct variables. It is not always **finitely generated** $B$-module what is actually said in $(2)$.

Comment: What do you mean by "ring of polynomials of $a_1,\ldots a_n$?

Comment: @user42912 Check out my answer again. I edited it.

Comment: Thank you very much, it was exactly I was looking for!